# CRA precache fails because of .LICENSE extension

Tags: .net-core, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps, workbox, sw-precache

So, we have a situation where in production the precache is failing on our PWA because of a weird .LICENSE file on our server that is giving us 404

specifically an error like this

```
uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url"
```

How we can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the fix is simple.

Our web-server returns only known file extensions, and .LICENSE is not one of them.

Just enable the `ServeUnknownFileTypes` flag on your StaticFileServer options [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.serveunknownfiletypes?view=aspnetcore-3.1)